# How do I change JSP and HTML indentation style in Eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, tabs, indentation

When I apply the automatic indentation in Eclipse IDE, on HTML or JSP files, I have that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But I would like to have that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Ceci est une page générée depuis une JSP.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I dont know how to add a tab after head and html ?

Comment: I am not sure, may be you can try options under : Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor

Comment: I already look at this preference but it would seem that we can also add words wich will be in-lines elements.